# MQTT Artemis broker, frequent reconnections when the device is on IPV6

Tags: ssl, tcp, mqtt, tls1.2, activemq-artemis

I am using the ActiveMQ Artemis Broker and publishing to it through a client application.

Behavior observed:

- When my client is IPV4 a TLS handshake is established and data is published as expected, no problems.
- When my client is IPV6 , I see frequent re-connections being established between the client and the server(broker) and no data is being published.

Details:

- When using IPV6 the client does a 3 way handshake and attempts to send data. It also receives a Server Hello and sends application data.
- But the connection terminates and again reconnects. This loop keeps occurring.
- The client library, network infrastructure, and broker are all completely the same when using IPv4 and IPv6.

The client logs say:

```
Idle network reply timeout.
```

The broker logs show an incoming connection request and also an CONNACK for it from the broker, e.g.:

```
MQTT(): IN << CONNECT protocol=(MQTT, 4), hasPassword=false, isCleanSession=false, keepAliveTimeSeconds=60, clientIdentifier=b_001, hasUserName=false, isWillFlag=false
MQTT(): OUT >> CONNACK connectReturnCode=0, sessionPresent=true
```

**What wire-shark (tcpdump) tells:**

- Before every re-connection(3 way handshake is done) I see this:

  ```
  Id  Src                                   Dest
  1  Broker(App Data)                      Client
  2  Broker(App Data)                      Client
  3  Client(ACK)                           Broker
  4  Client(ACK)                           Broker
  5  Broker(FIN,ACK)                       Client
  6  Client(FIN,ACK)                       Broker
  7  Broker (ACK)                          Client
  8  Client (SYN)                          Broker
  9  Broker (SYN/ACK)                      Client
  10  Client (ACK)                          Broker
  ```

Then the 3 way handshake (Client hello, Change Cipher Spec, Server Hello) and the above repeats again.

Based on packets 5, 6, & 7 I have concluded that the connection is being terminated by the broker (server). The client acknowledges termination and then again attempts to reconnect as it is an infinite loop attempting re connection and publishing.

I am looking at network level analysis for the first time and even wireshark. I'm not sure if my analysis is right.

Also have hit a wall, not sure why re-connection is occurring only when the device is IPV6. Also I don't see any `RST` to indicate termination of connection.

Broker is also sending a `CONNACK` (from broker logs), but still no data is sent, just attempts to reconnect not sure why.

Also, I see a few I see a few:

- Out-of-Order TCP (when src is broker)
- Spurious Re-transmission
- DUP ACK (src is client)

Not sure if this is important.

Any headers on what is going on?

Comment: @JustinBertram
```MQTT(): IN << CONNECT protocol=(MQTT, 4), hasPassword=false, isCleanSession=false, keepAliveTimeSeconds=60, clientIdentifier=b_001, hasUserName=false, isWillFlag=false

MQTT(): OUT >> CONNACK connectReturnCode=0, sessionPresent=true```

this is all the broker logs show, frequent connection IN and CONNACK, nothing more.

Comment: yes it is the same

Comment: sorry,yup that happens when IPV4 after CONNACK publishing happens.
when IPV6 aftter CONNACK again re-connection happens .i.e we see IN << CONNECT and CONNACK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231935/discussion-between-abhilash-gopalakrishna-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: @JustinBertram did more extensive research. the problem was with a LB setting in the network.
LB had a default connection timeout which was lesser than the keep-alive time set by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due to a LB setting which had a default connection time out of 30 secs , lesser than the connection timeout set by the client.